# How to merge multpile c files into a shared library for foreign function interface

Tags: c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, ffi

I have been following these instructions(http://jonisalonen.com/2012/calling-c-from-java-is-easy/) on how to create a shared library, but these instructions only show how to do it with one file. When I use this file, that I made into a shared library, the .so file can't call other .c files in the same place. How do i compile all the c files so that i can make a merged shared library that is accessible through java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create your object files with `-fPIC`:

```
gcc -fPIC -c file1.c
```

This creates `file1.o`. (same for `file2.c`, `file3.c` and so on).

2) Link it in a shared library.

```
gcc -shared -o library.so file1.o file2.o file3.o
```

Adjust accordingly for additional compiler flags, include paths from other stuff you're using etc.